# WPF: Custom Window

Tags: wpf, window

There are many articles that described how to create a custom shaped window in WPF but none of them (at least I can't find any) described how can build a reusable one such as inheriting from it in other windows.

I have tried to create a ControlTemplate from my custom window. The problem is with the Close button and the MoveDrag() method.

If I wire the event to one of my other controls in ControlTemplate their Parent property is null, so I can not drag or close the window.

Does anyone have any ideas how can I create a reusable custom window template or something?

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear on what you're asking for. Perhaps a minimal code sample would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such things as visual inheritance in WPF. (no xaml inheritance to be more specific)

For your specific issue, instead of inheriting, you could create a CustomForm as a template (with a big empty container in the middle), and then create all your other forms as usercontrols that fill that container.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the window object containing the control:

```
Window.GetWindow(myControl)
```